# Are R1s preferred over R2s in funding applications?

Tags: funding, computer-science, job-search, ranking

I have two tenure track assistant professor offers from two US schools, close in university ranking to each other (US news) but one is R1 and the other is R2.

I’m more inclined to the R2 offer. I am wondering if the status of the university (R1/R2) makes any difference to the funding agencies, national and private, IOW, if my (future) proposals will be viewed differently.

For context: department CS, area AI. The departmental ranking (again from USnews) is significantly higher in the R1 than the R2 one.

Comment: Note that the difference between R1 and R2 schools isn't quality. It is scope and scale. R1's have strong research requirements in many fields, R2's in fewer. An R2 can have an excellent research reputation in some field, even a single field, and not others.

Answer (score 8):

R1s are not preferred over R2s (unless you propose something that your institution does not have the facilities to support). The trade-off will likely be the difference in grad students you can recruit and expectations for tenure. I've been on multiple federal grant review panels and the institution ranking or classification has never been discussed, and panels are in fact explicitly told to be aware of and avoid implicit bias towards institutions (positive or negative).